# data from external json file in photoeditorsdk

Tags: javascript, json, photoeditorsdk

I am unable to load the stickers via extrnal file from server.getting this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDicj.jpg

i have added below highlighted code in photoeditorreactui.js

```
  // Then post-processing
      'radial-focus', 'linear-focus', 'sprite', 'border', 'watermark'],
      controlsOptions: {

            sticker: {
      stickersJSONPath: 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers.json?jsoncallback=?', // Treated as JSONP request

      replaceStickers: false // `additionalStickers` replaces all other stickers
    }


          }
    });

my stickers json  file is this. i tried different format but none is working. evertime it shows loading.... then shows timeout error.. i changed timeout to 85 seconds from 5 seconds then also it is giving timeout error of 5 seconds and not loading stickers from external source. stickers.json is in same server as all files.


stickers.json file


[
{
      'name': 'glasses',
      'label': 'Glasses',
      'stickers': [{
        'name': 'glasses-nerd',
        'label': 'Nerd glasses',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/glasses-nerd.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/glasses-nerd.png',
            'width': 221,
            'height': 91
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'glasses-normal',
        'label': 'Normal glasses',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/glasses-normal.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/glasses-normal.png',
            'width': 249,
            'height': 87
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'glasses-shutter-green',
        'label': 'Green shutter glasses',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/glasses-shutter-green.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/glasses-shutter-green.png',
            'width': 235,
            'height': 89
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'glasses-shutter-yellow',
        'label': 'Yellow shutter glasses',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/glasses-shutter-yellow.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/glasses-shutter-yellow.png',
            'width': 236,
            'height': 89
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'glasses-sun',
        'label': 'Sun glasses',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/glasses-sun.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/glasses-sun.png',
            'width': 250,
            'height': 87
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      'name': 'hats',
      'label': 'Hats',
      'stickers': [{
        'name': 'hat-cap',
        'label': 'Cap',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/hat-cap.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/hat-cap.png',
            'width': 237,
            'height': 189
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'hat-cylinder',
        'label': 'Cylinder',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/hat-cylinder.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/hat-cylinder.png',
            'width': 225,
            'height': 176
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'hat-party',
        'label': 'Party hat',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/hat-party.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/hat-party.png',
            'width': 140,
            'height': 226
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'hat-sheriff',
        'label': 'Sheriff hat',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/hat-sheriff.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/hat-sheriff.png',
            'width': 251,
            'height': 129
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      'name': 'beards',
      'label': 'Beards',
      'stickers': [{
        'name': 'mustache-long',
        'label': 'Long mustache',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/mustache-long.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/mustache-long.png',
            'width': 199,
            'height': 182
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'mustache1',
        'label': 'Brown mustache',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/mustache1.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/mustache1.png',
            'width': 238,
            'height': 106
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'mustache2',
        'label': 'Black mustache',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/mustache2.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/mustache2.png',
            'width': 250,
            'height': 82
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'mustache3',
        'label': 'Brown mustache',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/mustache3.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/mustache3.png',
            'width': 250,
            'height': 94
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      'name': 'misc',
      'label': 'Misc',
      'stickers': [{
        'name': 'heart',
        'label': 'Heart',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/heart.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/heart.png',
            'width': 185,
            'height': 174
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'pipe',
        'label': 'Pipe',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/pipe.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/pipe.png',
            'width': 240,
            'height': 112
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'snowflake',
        'label': 'Snow flake',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/snowflake.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/snowflake.png',
            'width': 204,
            'height': 171
          }
        }
      }, {
        'name': 'star',
        'label': 'Star',
        'images': {
          'mediaThumb': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/thumb/star.png',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 100
          },
          'mediaBase': {
            'uri': 'http://xxxxxx.com/yyyy/photo-editor/assets/stickers/base/star.png',
            'width': 201,
            'height': 191
           }
        }
      }]
    }]
```

tried all possible json format but none is working, if anyone has experience with img.ly sdk it will be great.

https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/editor/customization/sticker#stickers-json-schema

here is the documentation.

here i am trying

http://test.com/kkjjjj/photo-editor/photo-editor1.php